# How to find the coordinates of these points?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Does anyone know any way or any algorithm that can exactly and/or numerically find the coordinates
of $n_{k}+2$ equally spaced points on the $(n_{k}-1)$-dimensional
unit sphere $S^{n_{k}-1}$ for some sequence of integers $1<n_{1}<n_{2}\cdots<n_{k}<\cdots$? Many thanks.

Comment: What does "equally spaced" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by *equally spaced*.

If you want that all points have pairwise identical distances, then this is not possible. This is only possible for at most $n+1$ points, but not more.

If you want to maximize the minimal distance of $n+2$ points in the $(n-1)$-sphere, you have to pick some of the vertices of the $n$-dimensional crosspolytope, that is $(\pm1,...,\pm 1)$.

Here is a reference to that:

- Conway, John Horton, and Neil James Alexander Sloane. *Sphere packings, lattices and groups*.

In Chapter 1, subsection 2.6 they introduce the function $A(n,\theta)$ to denote the maximal number of points on an $(n-1)$-dimensional sphere (in $\Bbb R^n$) so that any two points have an angle of at least $\theta$ between them.
They state

1. $A(n, \pi/2)=2n$ (for the vertices of the crosspolytope), and
2. $A(n,\theta)\le n+1$ for $\theta>\pi/2$ (for the vertices of a simplex).

Now, let's say you have an arrangement of $n+2$ points that maximizes the minimal distance between any two points.
Let $\theta$ be this (angular) distance.
By 2., we know that $\theta \le\pi/2$, and by 1. we know that $\pi/2$ can be achieved (and we actually have space to add more points).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but why does one have to pick some of the vertices of the n-dimensional crosspolytope? Thanks.

Comment: Since you are saying "this is only possible for at most n+1 points, but not more", how about 6 and 20 points on $S^2$? Thanks.

Comment: @nancyD I will edit the answer later, to add some further information (right now, I can't). For now: for 6 and 20 points the pairwise distance is not identical, e.g. for 6 points there are antipodal pairs of vertices, and non-antipodal ones.

Comment: @nancyD I updates the answer with a reference.

Comment: $6$ and $20$ points on $S^2$ would seem to be irrelevant, nancy, since your question specifically asks for the number of points to be greater than the dimension by exactly three.

Comment: @M.Winter Thank you for your update with the reference. I am trying to read the reference and understand your answer. Thanks a lot.